# is bootstrap twitter typeahead working in the navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I tried lot of way to integrate a typeahead in the navbar but the layout never works correctly in responsive.

Is there someone who have a working example of bootstrap twitter typeahead in a navbar that works in responsive mode?

Comment: Have you implemented the typeahead using the info on adding forms to the Navbar found here?: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Comment: yes. the problem is that in a case the dropdown is not correctly sized http://clip2net.com/s/2LsqZ and in on the other case, the layout is completely broken on iphone/small screen.

Comment: FWIW, I had the same issue and ended up just hiding the typeahead dropdown on mobile screens.